# How to edit complex nested object in Mantine React Table?

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I have an array of objects and each object has it's own nested object:

```
{
"allowOverwrite":false,
"eq1":0,
"between1and6":1,
"higher5":2
}
```

Also i use Mantine React Table to display data. So i want to display these objects inside their own cells, there is no problem with it (see 1st image)
but i can't figure out how to edit this cell. MRT's docs says "see MRT_EditCellTextInput source code for more info", anyway, i dont understand how to apply their code to my case

I expect that when i click "edit" button, the modal (by default) appears and there are few textfields and a checkbox inside, so i can edit values of this nested object separately

[image]